# Sharepoint 2007 Configuration

Tags: sharepoint-online

I did a sharepoint 2007 installation, but  I do not know how to move on.

I need to create a Farm so that the users of the network through the browser can insert documents like, excel, pdf, Word and etc.

In Central Administration, i have a red message stating "Server Farm Configuration Not Complete"

Someone has a step-by-step on how to achieve this goal?

Thanks.

Comment: SharePoint 2007? or any onther SharePoint version?

Comment: No, only SharePoint  2007

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whats the purpose of Moss 2007 rather we have the SharePoint 2019 version available. 2007 is out of support life cycle.

Here are some step by step guide for Moss 2007.

[Steps of Installing MOSS 2007](http://www.geekswithblogs.net/emanish/archive/2006/09/12/90979.aspx)
[SharePoint 2007 Server Installation Step by step Process](https://a2zmoss.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/sharepoint-2007-server-installation-step-by-step-process/)

or check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=es75q8Jc3cI)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I need to install Sharepoint 2007 because I'm going to make a migration to the 2010 version and after to 2013